# JavaFX - ComboBox listener for its textfield

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm not even sure how to correctly ask this question, but is it possible to add listener here (on this textfield within `ComboBox`), when `ComboBox` is set as editable:

[image]

Currently I'm using 2 kinds of listeners for `ComboBox`. Mouse and Change listener. `MouseListener` for clicks on `ComboBox` and `ChangeListener` for selection of items within `ComboBox`. But I have no idea what kind of listener should I use to listen for text entry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are only interested in the editable area (`TextField`) of `ComboBox`, use `ComboBox#getEditor()`.

```
ComboBox combobox = new ComboBox();
combobox.setEditable(true);
combobox.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, 
                                    String oldValue, String newValue) {
        System.out.println("Text changed");
    }
});
```

The last text will be set to `ComboBox`'s `valueProperty` when the `TextField` loses its focus.

Comment: Worked for me too and has the advantage of being called every time the user changes the text rather than only when the control changes focus or clicks like is the case with `combobox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){...}`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX, you can attach notification events to any property that a control may possess.  In your case, you need to decide if you want to be notified if the combobox's editable value field changes or if you want to receive key events each time the user enters a key into the value field.

If you simply wish to act on an event in the case that the combobox's value field changes, you can register a ChangeListener for its valueProperty which is defined in the Javadocs as follows:

> valueProperty: The value of this ComboBox is defined as the selected
>   item if the input is not editable, or if it is editable, the most
>   recent user action: either the value input by the user, or the last
>   selected item.